# converting audio file format after upload

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, format, file-conversion

I am developing a phonegap application for iOS and Android. In iOS, recorded sound format is .wav and in android, it's .amr/.mp3. After recording, audio file gets uploaded to a web server.

I need to convert these files from .amr/.wav to .mp3 after upload - what options do I have?

1. I've read about ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php. Will that work with shared hosting? If yes, can someone provide any link to install it?
2. Any converter, which will work with shared hosting of justHost cPanel?
3. any php class which can send my audio file to ffmpeg server and get back mp3 file? Just thinking.
4. Any other option?

I don't mind the method - I need the the required output.

Comment: Of course, there are services like zencoder as well.

Comment: hi Prasoon. Did you manage to get this to work? I am facing a similar issue in my project

Comment: @ambit Sadly NO! There is SoX [link](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), but I couldn't install it properly. Please check and let me know if it works. If you find any method which works - please let me know.

Comment: Will let you know if I find anything. So far, I haven't found anything that works easily with shared hosting